# Cannot ssh into server through VPN

Tags: ssh, osx, vpn, sftp

I'm trying to `ssh` into my university server via vpn (PPTP). I'm on an Mac OSX 10.11.4. (El capitan)

Unfortunately, I get the following error:

```
Adams-MacBook-Pro:~ adamG$ ssh gadam@xxx.xx.xx.ac.uk
ssh: connect to host xxx.xx.xx.ac.uk port 22: Operation timed out
```

I tried to ping xxx.xx.xx.ac.uk.

```
11 packets transmitted, 11 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
```

I also tried to `telnet xxx.xx.xx.ac.uk 22`,
but it doesn't work.

I also cannot do `sftp` through FileZilla.

I can `ssh` into the server using my iPad actually using VPN (PPTP), it works fine there.

Could someone help please?

Comment: One simple test to do is to disconnect from vpn and reconnect and try again.

Comment: Tried that one already

Comment: The joys of El Capitan...if possible try it with yosemite. El Capitan beta was known to have PPTP bugs. PPTP is being discontinued in several firewall products as an obsolete and insecure protocol...Also, any firewall, using Little Snitch, by any chance?